# Adding the same element after using remove() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to add points  in one dive area on tap.
Now I want to remove old tapped points to update it, I am using jQuery `remove()` function. **It work fine but after that it's not showing me next tapped points on that div.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function (e) {
        $(".myimg").first().clone().offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $('.myimg').remove();
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing main clone element, with class `.myimg`, you need to save that as backup, because when you're clicking on that div, you need to use that img for cloning,

Here's [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/szCAL/10/)

I added another class name to that cloned element and removing those dots with that class name.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove only the clones, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $('.myimg').first();
    $("#test").click(function (e) {
        el.clone().offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        }).appendTo('body').addClass("clone");
    });
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $('.clone').remove();
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/13/

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new element instead of cloning, the issue solves it self, and you can get rid of the first annoying element :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function (e) {
        $('<img />', {
            style   : 'left: '+e.pageX+'px;top:'+ e.pageY + 'px;height: 10px;width:10px',
            src     : 'http://www.nystce.nesinc.com/images/tests_circle.gif',
            'class' : 'myimg'
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $('.myimg').remove();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/14/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the element again in order to start displaying position

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
        $('.myimg').remove();
        $('#test').append("<img class='myimg' width='10' src='http://www.nystce.nesinc.com/images/tests_circle.gif' height='10' />");
    });
```

checkout [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/11/)